# Workflow 4 under AppFabric error in AppDashboard when using pipes

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I've successfully got a few workflows going with Server AppFabric.

What i have noticed however is that when i try to use namePipeBinding to communicate with the workflow then the call works successfully for the client (the call is marked As IsOneWay=true in the interface definition for the service) but in the AppFabric dashboard i can see the message being processed successfully and then we get the call appearing as a 'Service Exception' with the following exception

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.IOException: The write operation failed, see inner exception. ---> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d). ---> System.IO.PipeException: There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.OnAsyncReadComplete(Boolean haveResult, Int32 error, Int32 numBytes)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.ReadAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult transportResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.EndRead()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceiveAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result, Message& message)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ErrorHandlingReceiver.EndTryReceive(IAsyncResult result, RequestContext& requestContext)
```

The workflow consists of two receive activities but it doesn't have any receiveandsendreply activitiies.

Everything works fine when i use http bindings.

Why is this error being reported in the dashboard?

Configuration details for the client app are shown below

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISLG" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ISLG" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />

                <security mode="Transport">
                  <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign"/>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netNamedPipeBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://vm-vsnet2010/TestWorkflowDeclarativeServiceLibrary/Service3.xamlx"
            binding="netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_ISLG"
            contract="SLGService.ISLG" name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ISLG">
            <identity>
                <servicePrincipalName value="host/VM-VSNET2010" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you submit the server binding configuration? They may differ and that's why the server can't receive data from the pipe.

Regards

Comment: There is / are no details in the config file server side.  To reiterate, the server does successfully process the requests it just that a lot of entries appear in the appfabric dashboard regarding the success of the workflow operations (see above).

Comment: Ok, now I understand better and it's weirder :)
Somehow it seems to be creating a duplex channel, so for some reason it's being called on a two way mode.
Are you using any correlation? Maybe this helps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wfprerelease/thread/47a94846-2191-454a-9ea8-1f8783e20b27